# get custompaint local position while zoom and move a widget with InteractiveViewer flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to get `localposition` of a `custompaint` canvas and i can make this for a constant center offcet
of the screen like in the provided code but i want to use `InteractiveViewer` to make zoom and move for
a `custompaint` so before moving `custompaint` i get the actual `localposition` inside the specified region `40*40`
from the center but after moving `custompaint` i got lost the `localposition` so i want to make the `center offcet` change according
to the `InteractiveViewer` offset of zoom and move , [image: the output behavior]

this is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ZoomAndPanWidget());
}

class ZoomAndPanWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ZoomAndPanWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ZoomAndPanWidgetState createState() => _ZoomAndPanWidgetState();
}

class _ZoomAndPanWidgetState extends State<ZoomAndPanWidget> {
  
  double yp = 15;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (details) {
            // Calculate the local position relative to the center of the canvas
            final center = Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2);
      
            // Calculate the distance from the tap to the center
      
            final distance = (details.localPosition - center);
            print(
                'details.localPosition = ${details.localPosition},center = $center');
            // Check if the tap is within 40*40
            print('distance.dx = ${distance.dx} , distance.dy = ${distance.dy}');
            if (distance.dx <= 20 &&
                distance.dx >= -20 &&
                distance.dy <= 20 &&
                distance.dy >= -20) {
              setState(() {
                yp = (yp == 15) ? 0 : 15;
              });
            }
          },
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            maxScale: 3,
            minScale: 0.5,
            boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
            constrained: false,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                painter: Drawpath(yp),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Drawpath extends CustomPainter {
  final double yp;

  Drawpath(this.yp);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double x = size.width / 2;
    double y = size.height / 2;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4;
    final paintr = Paint()..color = Colors.red;

    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(x - 40, y)
      ..lineTo(x - 10, y);
    final path2 = Path()
      ..moveTo(x - 10, y)
      ..lineTo(x + 10, y - yp);
    final path3 = Path()
      ..moveTo(x + 10, y)
      ..lineTo(x + 40, y);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(x, y), width: 40, height: 40), paintr);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path3, paint);

    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(x, y), width: 2 * x, height: 2 * y),
        paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Drawpath oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: you need [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransformationController-class.html) and `MatrixUtils` class (most likely `transformPoint` or `transformRect` method)

Comment: @pskink thanks it works well after using `MatrixUtils` and this is the modified part :                      `final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;                  final tapPoint = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
            final localPoint = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(
              _controller.value.clone()..invert(),tapPoint, );`

Comment: you don't need that `RenderBox` and `renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition)` just use `detail.position`, also use `Matrix4.inverted` ctor instead of clone and invert

Comment: btw I completely forgot about [toScene()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransformationController/toScene.html) method

Comment: ok i will modify it to `detail.position`